# php add class to an image slider

Tags: php, image, class, foreach, slider

I am trying to add a class to an image slider, i managed to add it to the img tag and it is working but it is not working when there are several images to the gallery, meaning the class 'zoooom' is effective only on the first image of the slider. Below is the for each code. How can I apply the class to each image of the slides? I guess I have to loop through using $image like class="" but where should i add "zoooom" then? None of the code I have been trying worked, I don't know PHP and have to fix this bug, any help would be appreciated, Thanks!

```
<ul class="product-slider">

    <?php 
    if( $images ): ?>

    <?php foreach( $images as $image ): ?>

    <li>
    <img class="zoooom" src="<?php echo $image['sizes']['large']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt']; ?>" style="max-width:80%;"/>
    </li>

    <?php endforeach; ?>

    <?php endif; ?>

</ul>
```

Comment: your code is fine it must set class on `<img>` what you getting in view source of slider html ? may be your class being over ride by `JS`

Comment: Hey, I inspected the console elements and the class zoom is applied to each image of the slider but for some reason it only shows the first images in the zoom window no matter which position image of the slider it is: http://www.norbertszlosantiques.com/products/magnificent-pair-commode-marquetry-bronze-style-louis-xvi-a-magnificent-pair-of-commode-in-marquetry-and-bronze-of-style-louis-xvi-signed-paul-sormani/

Answer (score 0):

you need to change your class using loop this code generate new class zoom1,zoom2,zoom3....
Try this

```
<ul class="product-slider">

<?php $i =1;
if( $images ): ?>

<?php foreach( $images as $image ): ?>

<li>
<img class="zoooom<?php echo $i; ?>" src="<?php echo $image['sizes']['large']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt']; ?>" style="max-width:80%;"/>
</li>

<?php $i++; endforeach; ?>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: I guess the OP wants a common class to be added on all the `img` tags, right @sarah_g

Comment: then you can use class="zoom  newclass<?php echo $i; ?>"

Comment: why you need a common class

Comment: I tried this code but it create an infinite loop i guess, I mean no image were displayed when I changed class="zoooom<?php echo $i; ?>" and adding $i++
is $i stands for image?

Comment: did you try this class class="zoom newclass<?php echo $i; ?>"

Comment: Yes I tried this too and it didn't work.
This is the website I am working on, and when you click on an image among the slider only the first one is shown in the zoom window
http://www.norbertszlosantiques.com/products/magnificent-pair-commode-marquetry-bronze-style-louis-xvi-a-magnificent-pair-of-commode-in-marquetry-and-bronze-of-style-louis-xvi-signed-paul-sormani/

Comment: there is jquery error open your console and check  =>   ReferenceError: google is not defined

Comment: check your custom.js                        ->   /* Google Map 

         ================================================== */

        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init);

Comment: Hey, I saw this error too I didn't know how to solve it, it is a WP site so I am having trouble finding the files to edit except for the css Stylesheet and the php files for single post, header etc... I am working on a custom theme. I don't think this is why the zoom is working only for the first image, I am still trying to loop over each image to zoom I can't find the right code for that the zoom only zoom the first picture of the slider.